# Why there is no output on CodeEval?

Tags: python

I am working on CodeEval's FIZZ BUZZ challenge, here is the link: https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/1/submit/?lid=1218578

Here is my code:

```
"""Sample code to read in test cases:

import sys
test_cases = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for test in test_cases:
    # ignore test if it is an empty line
    # 'test' represents the test case, do something with it
    # ...
    # ...
    test = test.strip()
    X, Y, N = (int(s) for s in test.split())
    result = ""
    for i in range(1, N+1):
        if i % X == 0 and i % Y == 0:
            result += "FB "
        elif i % X == 0:
            result += "F "
        elif i % Y == 0:
            result += "B "
        else:
            result += str(i) + " "

    print (result.strip())

test_cases.close()
"""
```

However, there is no output according to CodeEval. What's the problem?

Comment: Rather than just adding a link, please describe the particular problem you are facing with proper error message.

Answer (score 0):

After checking on the website, It appears that you surrounded all your code with triple quote which is the same than commenting it. I corrected the question accordingly. Just remove the triple quote and everything should work